# how to use OnDateChangedListener

Tags: android

How to use `OnDateChangedListener`

I have `datepicker` dialog it shows well. But I want to use `OnDateChangedListener` using `datepicker` programmatically like `DatePicker picker = new DatePicker(this);`

Answer (score 0):

see this [DatePicker Example](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html)

```
DatePicker picker = new DatePicker(this);
picker.init(2012, 8, 8, new OnDateChangedListener() {
@Override
public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {
    // Your Code Here.

}
});
```

Comment: actually i create Datepicker in button click and date picker dialog will not showing if i click the button.i dont know how to display the date picker dialog using date picker

Comment: @user1500635 : you have try my answer?